# Balanced Binary Tree Solution

Tags: c#, .net, tree, binary-tree

I solved a problem in LeetCode for binary balanced tree and it's pretty basic. I've a doubt with the solution and here's what I did so far - [Balanced Binary Tree](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DlyaxQ). My attempt was as follows and luckily it got accepted:

```
static bool IsBalanced(BinaryTree root) {
    isBalanced = true;

    int chk = CheckBalance(root.Root, 0);

    return isBalanced;
  }

  static int CheckBalance(TreeNode root, int depth) {
    if (root == null)
      return 0;

    int left = CheckBalance(root.left, depth + 1);
    int right = CheckBalance(root.right, depth + 1);

    if (Math.Abs(left - right) > 1)
      isBalanced = false;
    return GetMax(left, right);
  }

  static int GetMax(int left, int right) {
    if (left > right)
      return left;
    else
      return right;
  }
```

**1st Input**:

```
       3
      / \
     9  20
        / \
       15  7
```

**Output**: True

**2nd Input**:

```
        1
       / \
      2   2
     / \
    3   3
   / \
  4   4
```

**Output**: False

For the first input, the tree is balanced and it returned true. But for the second one, it should return false as it isn't balanced. But with my sample input in the fiddle, returns true. Is it some kind of bug or error as I am doing recursive call for all possible trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this:

In `CheckBalance` you never use `depth`. Since you say it works on the challenge site, I must assume you retyped the code and did not enter the same code here. The return statement for the base case should be:

```
return depth;
```

The main issue is however that your `Add` function creates node instances with value `null`. This means that for the second example input you actually create this tree:

```
            ___1___
           /       \
        __2__       2
       /     \     / \
      3       3 null null
     / \     / \
    4   4 null null
```

... and that tree is balanced!

It is not trivial to write an `Add` function that can do the job as expected, without keeping track of whether a `null` child was the default value, or was really populated with `null`. This difference determines where the next value should be inserted.

Therefore I would suggest a different approach. Provide a `BinaryTree` constructor that receives the whole input as an array, and which then iterates that array in a controlled way, inserting values where they are supposed to end up:

```
  public BinaryTree(int?[] data) {
    if (data.Length == 0) return;
    
    var queue = new Queue<TreeNode>();
    Root = new TreeNode(data[0]);
    queue.Enqueue(Root);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < data.Length; i++) {
      TreeNode presentNode = queue.Dequeue();
      if (data[i] != null) {
        presentNode.left = new TreeNode(data[i]);
        queue.Enqueue(presentNode.left);
      }
      i++;
      if (i >= data.Length) break;
      if (data[i] != null) {
        presentNode.right = new TreeNode(data[i]);
        queue.Enqueue(presentNode.right);
      }
    }
  }
```

Using this constructor, you can now run your test case like this:

```
    int?[] data = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, null, null, 4, 4};  
    BinaryTree aBinaryTree = new BinaryTree(data);
    bool status = IsBalanced(aBinaryTree);
```

Comment: Hello @trincot! I tried your way but seems like it still returns **True** for the second input. Here's the updated fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/DlyaxQ.

Comment: But you didn't apply the first fix (`return depth`). Like I wrote, I think this is a mistake you made when typing your code in your question, because you write *"luckily this got accepted"* -- which is impossible if you really used that version of your code, because then you will always get the same result.

Comment: Updated. Can you please check?

Comment: I already checked in my own environment and it returns False when the fix is made. I don't see the fix in your code.

Comment: See it in this updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pCyfji

Comment: Ok, I did a mistake while returning this - `if (root == null) return 0;`. Thanks for clarifying, I'll debug for sometime to check this out.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you replaced the wrong `return` statement. The bottom one should remain as it was. Only the `return 0;` was wrong.

Comment: So my understanding is here, when I returned 0 for null, it actually added it as a node for the tree and considered as balanced one. Right?

Comment: Right, as you can see in the "picture" I presented in my answer. To debug, I'd advice to add a print function to your `BinaryTree` class, so you have a visual representation of the tree.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to do it.

Comment: I tried to print the tree structure, that seems to be fine @trincot. Here's the fiddle that tried so far - https://dotnetfiddle.net/aAoY8H. You can copy and paste the code to run. For the time being, I tried to print all nodes in the constructor level that means I like to add nodes in the same tree for debugging. But for the loop, the tree gets printed four times though my purpose is to add all nodes in one tree. Did some tweaks but failed. Anything you can suggest?

Comment: If you cannot make the printing work, look at how others have done it or post a new question.